# What is the domain of $f(x,y) = xy/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, domain-theory

I think the domain is all real except $(0,0)$, because this point anulates the denominator, but what about with the fact that the limit exists when $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is all real numbers except when $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0$. But, this occurs when $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ which, in turn, occurs only when $x=y=0$. Therefore,

$$ \text{Domain}(f) = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \} $$

Comment: But in $(0,0)$ we have the indeterminate form 0/0, that can be eliminated with limit manipulations.

Comment: @RonaldBecerra : The function as given does not contain a limit.  If you would like to describe a different function that uses a limit to have a different domain, you are free to do so.  But this other function with a limit in it is not the function you gave in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be made continuous, with domain $\mathbb{R}^2$, by defining $f(0,0)=0$, but the domain of the given function excludes $(0,0)$.